# PHP to show ISO DVD image on local server

Tags: php, iso, dvd

is there any way I can show an ISO image (from a DVD movie I burned) on my local server.  I want to watch my ISO images from my local server on any of my tablets and such.

Any ideas on the best way to proceed?

Comment: Am seeing this kind of request for the first time in my life ... PHP & Movie are not friends ... the are better DVD sharing applications online .. `use Google`

Comment: worlds first real programming problem

Comment: PHP is **NOT** the answer to all of life's programming problems. Far from it. It's more offten the start of life's programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tackling this wrong. Convert your dvd's to MP4 (if you want to use on most devices, xVid works better) then host them.  ISO's aren't gonna do you much good.

Comment: Good call... problem is, that would be a HUGE mp4... but I will mess around with it.  See what I can do.

Comment: Yes Movies are big files, but A good quality rip won't have to exceed 1GB

Comment: Adam... do you have any suggestions on software to go from iso to mp4?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what your objective is, but with HTTP ranges, and disabling gzip compression (both achievable through `.htaccess` files) you can make videos 'stream'.
It's not really related to PHP, unless you want to have PHP to behave like an HTTP server...

Comment: Ok... way out of my league.  I have never streamed videos before... so this is foreign to me.  Any links or suggestions on a good tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

You need a video playing application that can play partially downloaded files. This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: Any suggestions?  on the type of application

Comment: I'm not sure which players have this capability, but maybe you could have a look at VLC or MPlayer (Windows/Linux/maybe Mac as well?). A better option is using SMB or NFS to share the ISO with the playback device, then you would just mount the directory containing the ISO and play it using your normal video player.

Comment: I have the "mount" option a couple times, but not sure how to go about this.  VLC plays ISO just fine... great in fact, but I need to serve the ISO on one of my server pages on my localhost so that any of my tablets or other computers can view the movie at any point.

Comment: If this is a linux server, have a look at Samba. If this is a windows server you should have a look at the built-in "file sharing" capabilities of windows. For macs there are similar things. When the directory containing the ISO has been shared, it can be mounted (thereby making it look like it is a part of the local filesystem) on the client. In windows, this would mean assigning it a drive letter (Z:\ for example). In Linux you can mount it using smbmount on, say, /mnt/isos/. Hope this helps.